# typing status / online status via GCM and xmpp

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I have finished developing my IM application on android (using xmpp & GCM), and I am using the gcm for buth UpPayload and DownPayloads..
and to notify the user that his partner is online/ofline I send messaage that my xmpp server "understand"
that tell the statuse.

```
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
 if(!isOnlineSent)
 {SendOnlineStatus("Online");
    isOnlineSent=true;}
 .
 .
 .
 .}
```

and the SendOnlineStatus look like:

```
 Intent OnlineMsg = new Intent();

    OnlineMsg.putExtra("action", "com.Esmaeel.sodfarim.sodfa01.MESSAGE");
    String nowtime = String.valueOf(EsTools.getCurrentTime());
    OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.TYPECLM, ConstantsGCM.ONST);
    OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.STATUS_on_of, Status);
    OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.TO_CLM, "-01");
    OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.FROMCLM, UUID);
    OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.MESSAGE_ID_CLM, regid + nowtime);
    OnlineMsg.putExtra(ConstantsGCM.NAME_CLM, "Name");


    final Bundle bndl = OnlineMsg.getExtras();
    new AsyncTask() {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            if (ggcm == null) {
                ggcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);

            }

            try {
                ggcm.send(PRO_ID + ConstantsGCM.GCM_SERVER, bndl.getString(ConstantsGCM.MESSAGE_ID_CLM), bndl); //// GCM_SERVER="gcm.googleapis.com"
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);
```

the server checks the value of

payload.get(ConstantsGCM.TYPECLM);
 if the type ONST the server reads the value    payload.get(ConstantsGCM.STATUS_on_of);
the valid valuse of  payload.get(ConstantsGCM.STATUS_on_of); is "online" OR "offline".

then the server update the user status and sends the new status to all the user's friends.

the same I do with Typing status but the last step I send just to the other side of the active chat.
but I get problems like "user apear online while he is offline, and some times apears typing when he is not.
any help or more effictive Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for the typing part, but for the status, maybe you should only send to the friends something like : "you should check the status of this user" then each friends phone will get the real status directly on the server. Hope it helps

Comment: it's not complete solution, when should I send? every time the coversation opened? OK, If he go Offline while we talk? NOT: no direct way to know if the app is visible, it is complex.

Comment: No, you send the message when the event happen (the user changes of status), but when the friends receive the message AND when they open the conversation (or whenever necessary), they check the status and display it.

Comment: here is the major problrm: the Case: you cannot know when the event happen (offline).. the user may press home button, so he if out of the conversation, but you cannot know (as developer you cannot send offline every time onPause Called, he mey navegate to another activity oR press home ) - as you give me a partial solution, I'll give you (V) >>

Comment: You can know when the user press home button : just send your status update in : onPause method : this method is called when you leave the activity (by pressing pause, or by lauching a new activity so make sure it fits your needs)

Comment: I cannot (or don't want) to send offline msg every time the user navigate in my app, he can leave the coversation but still in the app in this case I don't wan't to send offline>>> So pressing home or Back to main screen of my app will call onPause..
and android control the [home] button so doesn't tell the app if it pressed.